# Is it safe to use onerror to serv .webp images for none supporting browsers?

Tags: javascript, php, html, image, browser

I am trying to serv `.webp` images, but some browsers doesnt support `.webp` extention,
I have searched arround and didnt find a real solution for that.

There are some solutions with js but they are causing render bloking error.

I was using onerror earlier I think it was ie 5.5+ and Safari 5.1+ something it was working perfectly.

I tried to serv .webp images with onerror, it works fine in opera, safari lates ver, chrome, ie 10 and not causing any problem, didint try on safari.

> I want to know if is it safe and ok for browsers to use ?

Here is how I use it in bootstrap slider.

```
<img src="images/posts/dc.webp" onerror="this.src = 'images/posts/dc.png'" class="img-fluid"/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution or understand my mistake why my code wasnt working.lol
My code wasnt working in slider, because I was adding same type of image dynamicly to both `srcset` that is why it wasnt working.

Here is the solution:

I get `$image` from database and `exlode();` it to get only name without extention like so :

```
$file_name = $row['img'];
$image = explode('.',$file_name);
```

And add to  like so:

```
<source srcset="uploads/large/<?php echo htmlspecialchars($image[0]);?>.webp" type="image/webp">

<img src="uploads/large/<?php echo htmlspecialchars($row['img']);?>" alt="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($row['title']);?>" class="img-fluid"/>
```

it looks working perfect right now, this question might help someone.

Answer (score 1):

How about a non-js solution?

```
<picture>
  <source srcset="images/posts/dc.webp" type="image/webp">
  <img src="images/posts/dc.png">
</picture>
```

Comment: That solution didnt work in bootstrap slider for me in chrome and opera, which is supporting .webp they didnt detect, but it works fine in html and simple image.

Comment: This is what I understood from your question and this is working fine for me in Chrome: https://jsfiddle.net/gkt3omv7/ - did I get you wrong?

Comment: do you use it in php codes in your site ? `<picture>
  <source srcset="images/posts/dc.webp" type="image/webp">
  <source srcset="images/posts/dc.png" type="image/png">
  <img src="images/posts/dc.png">
</picture>` This is what I tried and didnt work in slider, but it works fine with simple images.